# How to use webpack with antd

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, antd

I try to customize a theme of antd with `webpack.config.js`, but I don't understand how it works. I want to customize the CSS with `less-loader`.

I follow this [link](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#How-to-do-it)

I have a `webpack.config.js :

```js
module.exports = {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [{
            loader: 'style-loader',
        }, {
            loader: 'css-loader', // translates CSS into CommonJS
        }, {
            loader: 'less-loader', // compiles Less to CSS
            options: {
                lessOptions: { // If you are using less-loader@5 please spread the lessOptions to options directly
                    modifyVars: {
                        'font-size-base': '140px'
                    },
                    javascriptEnabled: true,
                },
            },
        }],
    }],
}
```

But the font size base doesn't change anyway.

Note: I develop a React application with TypeScript.

Comment: This doc looks too old so it's unlikely to work I think. Do you hav a reproducible repo anyway?

Comment: I succeeded with CracoLessPlugin thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
npm install craco-less --save
```

in my package.json (for craco less add this):

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^5.6.4",
    "craco-less": "^1.17.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "craco eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "less": "^4.0.0",
    "less-loader": "^7.2.1"
  }
}
```

At the root of the project i had a craco.config.js :

```js
const CracoLessPlugin = require('craco-less');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        {
            plugin: CracoLessPlugin,
            options: {
                lessLoaderOptions: {
                    lessOptions: {
                        modifyVars: { '@primary-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);' },
                        javascriptEnabled: true,
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    ],
};
```

If you want to modify the theme indicate the modification in modifyVars
Vars of antd : https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#Ant-Design-Less-variables

And in my react component i had :

```js
import './competenceGrid.less';
```

The competenceGrid.less :

```css
@import '~antd/dist/antd.less';

/*some css*/
}
```